# Runtime error when using push_back() on smart pointer to vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, runtime-error

I am trying to fill a vector, by dereferencing a smart-pointer. During runtime the program crashes after one iteration of the first "for" loop used for entering the variable input.

```
using namespace std;

class Measurement
{
protected:
    int sample_size;
    string label;
    shared_ptr <vector<double>> data;
public:
    // parameterised constructor
    Measurement(string pLabel, int pSample_size)
    {
        label = pLabel;
        sample_size = pSample_size;
        cout << "Please input your dataset one entry at a time:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < sample_size; i++)
        {
            double input;
            cin >> input;
            data->push_back(input); // NOT WORKING???
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Measurement A("xData", 5);
    return 0;
}
```

When using the VS debugger it shows that an exception is thrown (Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Vector_alloc > >::_Myend(...) returned 0xC.) in the vector file, specifically lines 1793 - 1795:

```
bool _Has_unused_capacity() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // micro-optimization for capacity() != size()
    return (this->_Myend() != this->_Mylast());
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Well, what is `data` pointing to???

Comment: Doesn't look like you ever allocated the object for the smart pointer.

Comment: Dereferencing a `nullptr` (also true for smart pointers) is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @alterigel yeah this is the error, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default constructed `shared_ptr` does not point to anything valid. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr:

> Constructs a shared_ptr with no managed object, i.e. empty `shared_ptr`.

You need to initialize it such that it points to valid object that it manages before you can use the underlying pointer. For example, change the constructor to:

```
Measurement(string pLabel, int pSample_size) : data(new std::vector<double>()) 
{
   ...
}
```

or

```
Measurement(string pLabel, int pSample_size) : data(std::make_shared<std::vector<double>>()) 
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Using `new` to initialize the smart pointer results in twice the allocations (~2x slower). Using `std::make_shared` allocates the space for the object and the tag together.

Comment: @CruzJean, please clarify what you mean by *twice the allocations*. You certainly don't mean twice the allocations for the `std::vector`, do you?

Comment: @RSahu By two allocations he means one for the object and one for the reference counter. I don't see any reason to use `new` and not `make_shared` here.

Comment: Yeah, this was the silly mistake, thanks. Implemented using `make_shared` instead of `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for `data` before use it:

```
Measurement(string pLabel, int pSample_size) {
   ...
   data = std::make_shared<vector<double>>();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized the ptr. Below demonstrates the use of [default initializers for member variables](https://arne-mertz.de/2015/08/new-c-features-default-initializers-for-member-variables/) and [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

You could easily add the ptr initialization to the initialization list, but since it doesn't depend on any constructor arguments. It's better to declare it's construction in the manner below to avoid a copy/paste error when creating additional constructors.

```
#include <iostream>                                                              
#include <vector>                                                                
#include <memory>                                                                

using namespace std;                                                             

class Measurement {                                                              
  protected:                                                                     
    int                        sample_size_;                                     
    string                     label_;                                           
    shared_ptr<vector<double>> data_{make_shared<vector<double>>()};             

  public:                                                                        
    // parameterised constructor                                                 
    Measurement( string pLabel, int pSample_size )                               
      : sample_size_( pSample_size )                                             
      , label_( pLabel )                                                         
    {                                                                            
        cout << "Please input your dataset one entry at a time:" << endl;        
        for ( int i = 0; i < sample_size_; i++ ) {                               
            double input;                                                        
            cin >> input;                                                        
            data_->push_back( input ); // NOT WORKING???                         
        }                                                                        
    }                                                                            

    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, Measurement const& op1 )            
    {                                                                            
        for ( auto& v : *op1.data_ )                                             
            os << v << " ";                                                      
        return os;                                                               
    }                                                                            
};                                                                               

int main()                                                                       
{                                                                                
    Measurement A( "xData", 5 );                                                 
    cout << A << endl;                                                           
    return 0;                                                                    
}
```

Output:

```
g++     example.cpp   -o example
Please input your dataset one entry at a time:
1
2
3
4
5
1 2 3 4 5
```